# Interpretar una variable de python que contiene codigo HTML

Tags: html, python, flask, scraping, table

Tengo una variable en un código Python llamada 'table' de tipo string en la cual guardo una tabla en formato html que he generado con la función tabulate (html tableformat).

```
table = "<table>...</table>"
```

Entonces, esta variable se la quiero pasar a una plantilla en html ({{table}}), pero únicamente consigo visualizarla como un literal, no he encontrado cómo conseguir que se interprete esa variable como un 'contenedor' de código html y que por tanto me muestre la tabla en la web.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola Mónica, estás en Stackoverflow **en español**, las preguntas aquí deben estar en español.

Comment: Bienvenida Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español, en caso contrario puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Perdón, llevo buscando varios días en enlaces en inglés y no me di cuenta. Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor completar un ejemplo reproducible? o al menos más detalle de "cómo" intentas interpretar python y html. ¿Flask? ¿Django?

Comment: Estoy empleando python para hacer web scrapping (extracción de datos de una página web) y esos datos los muestro en una página web sencilla, pasándole las variables, todo mediante Flask. No sé si es de ayuda...

Answer (score 1):

El código que utilizo

{% block content %}

```
{{variable | safe}}
```

{% endblock content %}

*Variable es la variable que contiene el string con código html. 
*Safe es el operador que lee el string en formato html almacenado.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2 para más información puede visitar ese enlace, ahí hay un hilo de discusión muy interesante.